# Formula result doesn't show, leaves blank cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet and between B2:B101, I have a number on each one. I am trying to get a rank on E2:E101, regarding to their given number. I tried using `=rank`, and it successfully shows the result in a tooltip, but when I press enter, it doesn't write the value.

[image]

The cell is blank.

View > All Formulas is unchecked, also tried with checked. No luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, looks like this is a bug, since rank is working as described for me. Any chance you can reproduce it in a new sheet, and share it with us?

Comment: There are similar reports on the Google Docs Editors official help forum in Spanish. I didn't take a look to the English forum yet. Please checkout it ->https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs

Comment: When this happens, is the save status "all changes saved"?

Answer (score 20):

Just had the same issue and it looks like it's just a bug that's easily fixed by reloading the page.

I had it on a document that I'd worked on in a previous browser session and all my existing formulas were fine but if I changed the inputs then the new results did not display. Also, any new formula failed to display results.

So it seems that for a particular browser session it fails to write formula results to the cell output.

Comment: I had the same issue now (2021). Using Chrome on Windows. I pressed F5 to reload to the page and the calculation results appeared. Thank you!
Someone ought to mark your answer as _the_ answer.

Comment: Had the same issue (2021), using MacOS and Firefox. Solved by refreshing.